# Putting data in TreeMap, causing duplicate entries

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, immutability, treemap

My first post on Stackoverflow so excuse me if I post it wrong...

So I have an `ArrayList<Person>` with a lot of personal data (fetched from a service over json, parsed and mapped to a POJO Person).
I'd like play with some statistics (draw graphs of weight loss/gain etc) from this data.

First of I insert all Person identifers (from the ArrayList in a HashSet to filter out duplicates leaving me with unique identifiers for each person.

I then want to have this structure:

```
HashMap<String, TreeMap<Date, Double> mapWithWeightPerPerson = new HashMap<>();
```

So what I am trying to do is add a Persons weight data, per date using a TreeMap inside a HashMap.
(weather this is a good design decision might be subject for discussion).

So for each identifier I loop through the ArrayList with all Person and add the persons record to a 
TreeMap with a key: Date (might go with String later), and a value: Double for the weight.
I then add the TreeMap to the outer HashMap and do this for all identifiers.

```
for (String identifier : setWithUniqueIdentifiers) {
    TreeMap<Date, Double> personWeightData = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Person person : listWithAlotOfPersons) {
        if (person.getSymbol().equalsIgnoreCase(identifier)) {
            System.out.println("Date = " + person.getDate());
            System.out.println("Weight = " + person.getWeight());

            personWeightData.put(person.getDate(), person.getWeight()));
            for (Double weight : personWeightData.values()) {
                System.out.println("Values inserted so far: " + weight);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("in key: " + identifier);
    mapWithWeightPerPerson.put(identifier, personWeightData);
}
```

When iterating over the mapWithWeightPerPerson and print all persons weight data for the dates I get the sane data over and over even though I did
personWeightData = new TreeMap<>(); above. This is how it looks like if I print the mapWithWeightPerPerson.

```
Date = 2015-03-05
Weight = 44.16
Values inserted so far: 44.16
Date = 2015-03-04
Weight = 43.99
Values inserted so far: 43.99
Values inserted so far: 44.16
Date = 2015-03-03
Weight = 42.62
Values inserted so far: 42.62
Values inserted so far: 43.99
Values inserted so far: 44.16
Date = 2015-03-02
Weight = 44.11
Values inserted so far: 44.11
Values inserted so far: 42.62
Values inserted so far: 43.99
Values inserted so far: 44.16
Date = 2015-02-27
Weight = 44.28
Values inserted so far: 44.28
Values inserted so far: 44.11
Values inserted so far: 42.62
Values inserted so far: 43.99
Values inserted so far: 44.16
in key: FatBob
Date = 2015-03-05
Weight = 12.77
Values inserted so far: 12.77
Date = 2015-03-04
Weight = 12.82
Values inserted so far: 12.82
Values inserted so far: 12.77
Date = 2015-03-03
Weight = 12.76
Values inserted so far: 12.76
Values inserted so far: 12.82
Values inserted so far: 12.77
Date = 2015-03-02
Weight = 12.91
Values inserted so far: 12.91
Values inserted so far: 12.76
Values inserted so far: 12.82
Values inserted so far: 12.77
Date = 2015-02-27
Weight = 12.93
Values inserted so far: 12.93
Values inserted so far: 12.91
Values inserted so far: 12.76
Values inserted so far: 12.82
Values inserted so far: 12.77
in key: SkinnyPete
Date = 2015-03-05
Weight = 360.30
Values inserted so far: 360.3
Date = 2015-03-04
Weight = 360.50
Values inserted so far: 360.5
Values inserted so far: 360.3
Date = 2015-03-03
Weight = 360.40
Values inserted so far: 360.4
Values inserted so far: 360.5
Values inserted so far: 360.3
Date = 2015-03-02
Weight = 365.40
Values inserted so far: 365.4
Values inserted so far: 360.4
Values inserted so far: 360.5
Values inserted so far: 360.3
Date = 2015-02-27
Weight = 363.80
Values inserted so far: 363.8
Values inserted so far: 365.4
Values inserted so far: 360.4
Values inserted so far: 360.5
Values inserted so far: 360.3
in key: BaldJohn
```

But when looping and printing mapWithWeightPerPerson I'd like it to be:

```
Person: FatBob
{2015-02-27=144.28, 2015-03-02=144.11, 2015-03-03=142.62, 2015-03-04=143.99, 2015-03-05=144.16}
Person: SkinnyPete
{2015-02-27=112.93, 2015-03-02=112.91, 2015-03-03=112.76, 2015-03-04=112.82, 2015-03-05=112.77}
Person: BaldJohn
{2015-02-27=363.8, 2015-03-02=365.4, 2015-03-03=360.4, 2015-03-04=360.5, 2015-03-05=360.3}
```

Looking forward for your answers.

Comment: What is setWithUniqueQuoteNames?

Comment: There's something you aren't showing us... For starters, why don't you add a print statement to indicate which entries you are adding to the map for each iteration (i.e. instead of at the back end, print it as you add them). That may tell you that something isn't right.  Side discussion: the approach you outline will work, but it's pretty inefficient. Better to loop through the data one time and create the personWeightData object if it doesn't already exist, then add data to the personWeightData (the existing one, or the one newly created).

Comment: @KevinDay to keep the code readable I removed print statements. I will add some more output asap.

Comment: Kind of looks like it's the same TreeMap in all three. How about instead of `personWeightData = new TreeMap<>();` you do `TreeMap<Date, Double> personWeightData = new TreeMap<>();`?

Comment: hope you have overrided hashcode, equals and compartTo properly.

Comment: Your code seems correct. How do you print mapWithWeightPerPerson and what is the result now?

Comment: @juunas I tried with TreeMap<Date, Double> personWeightData = new TreeMap<>(); but same result.

Comment: @greyfairer 
Iterator it = mapWithWeightPerPerson.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
 Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
 System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
 it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
Did the job

Answer (score 0):

You've got the same result for all entries in mapWithWeightPerPerson, so the problem could be,

1. The TreeMap instance is the same among all entries.
2. You add all person data into each TreeMap

To verify whether it's caused by first reason, you can iterate the mapWithWeightPerPerson and log out the original hash for the values, if they are different, it's not the reason.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, TreeMap<Date, Double> entry : mapWithWeightPerPerson>) {
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(entry.getValue()));
}
```

To verify whether it's caused by second reason, you can add debug log in following line,

```
if (person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(identifier)) {
    System.out.println(String.format("identifier %s, person name %s", identifier, person.getname()));
    personWeightData.put(person.getDate(), person.getWeight());
}
```

If there's multiple log for each identifier, then the condition in if clause is wrong.

Comment: 1: 
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(entry.getValue()));
Returned:
1874154700
1632392469
2008362258

2: System.out.println(String.format("identifier %s, person name %s", identifier, person.getname())); gives:
identifier FatBob, person name FatBob
identifier BaldJohn, person name BaldJohn
identifier SkinnyPete, person name SkinnyPete

Answer (score 0):

Error was in my printing of mapWithWeightPerPerson (HashMap):

```
for (Object o : mapWithWeightPerPerson.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Person: " + o);
    Collection collection = mapWithWeightPerPerson.values();
    Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

When changed to:

```
Iterator it = mapWithWeightPerPerson.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

It works with output:

```
FatBob = {2015-02-27=44.28, 2015-03-02=44.11, 2015-03-03=42.62, 2015-03-04=43.99, 2015-03-05=44.16}
SkinnyPete = {2015-02-27=12.93, 2015-03-02=12.91, 2015-03-03=12.76, 2015-03-04=12.82, 2015-03-05=12.77}
BaldJohn = {2015-02-27=363.8, 2015-03-02=365.4, 2015-03-03=360.4, 2015-03-04=360.5, 2015-03-05=360.3}
```